# Possible questions for migration

Tags: discussion

Sometimes other StackExchange sites have questions that might be more appropriate here.  For example, folks could periodically visit this query to find some:

- [CSTheory questions on crypto with no answers](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bcr.crypto-security%5d%20answers%3a0)

and then make that suggestion in a comment, or request that a moderator migrate the question here

Please add any other similarly helpful searches below.

Comment: +1. Can I suggest making a public tagset (or whatever they're called now), for all q's across sites, that would be more appropriate here? That way you wont have to keep hitting the different sites...

Comment: nevermind, try this out: http://stackexchange.com/filters/516/off-site-security?sort=unanswered. Feel free to change it (if you can, or tell me and I will).

Answer (score 6):

Similar searches on ServerFault

- [[security], no answer](https://serverfault.com/search?tab=newest&q=[security]%20answers%3a0)
- [[compromise], no answer](https://serverfault.com/search?tab=newest&q=[compromise]%20answers%3a0)
- [[hacking], no answer](https://serverfault.com/search?tab=newest&q=[hacking]%20answers%3a0)
- [[auditing], no answer](https://serverfault.com/search?q=[auditing]+answers%3A0)
- [[audit], no answer](https://serverfault.com/search?q=[audit]+answers%3A0)

Answer (score 2):

I'm of two minds on this. We generally avoid migrating to beta sites until we're quite certain the beta site will prosper and grow.

If a question is *strongly* on topic for this narrower site, but was asked on a broader site, consider:

- is the question languishing on the broader site? Does it have answers? Good answers?
- is it a new question or an old question?

More specifically, if it is ...

1. a new question
2. a good, well written question
3. *strongly* on-topic for the narrower site
4. languishing a bit on the larger site

I can support migrating them if all (or most of) these criteria is met, so flag them on the source site as such.

Comment: I can definitely understand criteria 2, 3, and 4. Why is it important that it is a new question? I would have thought the opposite - cant really be considered "languishing", if it was just asked...

Comment: BTW, I wouldnt consider ITsec a "narrower" site, but there is only partial overlap with the other site(s). Like any good Venn diagram... However, we have found that some questions, while on-topic for both sites, will get *more correct* answers from e.g. here. That is, you can ask a programmer or sysadmin a security question, and you're likely to get an answer, but its not assured to be the *right* answer. We've seen that time and time again...

Comment: There are a good range of questions we like to suggest for migration to Security if they have a specific security issue, and this obviously helps our growth however we also try to make sure we migrate out questions with no actual security relevance that should be on SU or SF so someone in that space can actually help the user. Almost all our migrates out are because the OP didn't read the FAQ.